# ARM IT block AS error

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm getting an error saying  addeq should be in IT block. From what I can tell it is.

Here is a cut of the code, at line 455 of [https://github.com/Jcfunk/g3_kernel/blob/lp-release/arch/arm/crypto/aesbs-core.S_shipped](http://aesbs-core.S)

```
    ite eq              @ Thumb2 thing, sanity check in ARM
    addeq   r6,r6,#0x10
    bne .Ldec_loop
```

Is addeq in an IT block?

From what I've googled, If-Then block, this IT block means that if EQ then ADDEQ else BNE .Ldec_loop.
I feel like it is, but I know nothing of arm assembly.

I'm using GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.25.1